# Is there a closed form formula of rotation matrix for objects with constant angular acceleration?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, rotation, angular-velocity

If an object is of constant angular velocity, then we can derived the closed form formula of rotation matrix thanks to the theory of linear ODEs (and the closed form of $e^{[\omega]}$):

$$R' = [\omega] R \Rightarrow R = e^{[\omega]t}R_0$$

However, if the things got a little more complicated, say, the object is of constant angular acceleration, namely $\omega(t) = \omega_0 + \alpha t$, is a closed form formula for $R$ also possible? Because the ODE
$$R' = [\omega_0 + \alpha t]R$$
fails to be linear.

EDIT: this system is indeed linear, but not autonomous. Anyway, I want to emphasis that this is not an ODE of the form $X' = AX$ where A is constant.

Comment: Pretty sure that the ODE you've given in your last equation *is* linear.  Perhaps you meant that it's not [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics))?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, thanks for the correction! I have edited my post. So does this mean there is a closed form of solution? Because I only remember the solution of X' = AX where A is constant

Comment: The answer is also in "consideration #2" here (consistent with  
Michael Seifert's great answer): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/630781/226902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically asking how to find the equation to the equation
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{R}}{dt} = M(t) \mathbf{R}.
$$
It can be shown that the answer can always be written as
$$
\mathbf{R}(t) = U(t) \mathbf{R}(0),
$$
for a linear operator $U(t)$, but the form of $U(t)$ depends on whether $M(t_1)$ commutes with $M(t_2)$ for all $t_1$ & $t_2$.  If $[M(t_1), M(t_2)] = 0$, then it can be shown that we have
$$
U(t) = \exp \left[ \int_0^t dt'\,  M(t') \right]. \tag{1}
$$
In particular, the case where $M$ is independent of $t$ means that $U(t) = e^{M t}$.

If, on the other hand, $[M(t_1), M(t_2)] \neq 0$, then we have to define the evolution operator in terms of a *Dyson series*:
$$
U(t) = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_0^t dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \cdots \int_0^{t_{n-1}} dt_{n} \, M(t_1) M(t_2) \cdots M(t_n) \tag{2}
$$
In other words, this is an infinite sum whose first term is a single integral, whose second term is a double integral, whose third term is a triple integral, etc.  This turns out to be equivalent to
$$
U(t) = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^t dt_1 \int_0^t dt_2 \cdots \int_0^t dt_{n} \, \mathcal{T} \left[ M(t_1) M(t_2) \cdots M(t_n) \right]
$$
where $\mathcal{T} \left[ M(t_1) M(t_2) \cdots M(t_n) \right]$ is the *time-ordered product* of the operators, i.e., the operators are reordered so that the arguments decrease from left to right in the string.  In this form, it is a bit easier to see how this might be equivalent to the form (1) above.

In particular, if we are talking about 2-D rotations, then the 2-D rotation group is *Abelian*, i.e., every rotation commutes with every other rotation and we're in the case where we can just write $U(t)$ in the form from (1) above.  If, on the other hand, we're talking about 3-D rotations, then it is no longer the case that two rotations at different times will commute (because 3-D rotations generally do not commute), and so we would have to deal with the form (2) for $U(t)$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide some materials regarding those 'it can be shown' parts? I would like to know their derivations too. Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: My reference for the above was Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, where he derives the result for the matrix differential equation $d\mathbf{v}/dt = M \mathbf{v}$ in the context of solving the time-dependent Schrödinger equation $d|\psi\rangle/dt = -(i H/\hbar) |\psi\rangle$.  I don't have the copy in front of me right now, but I believe that the results are outlined in Chapter 2 and there's a proof (or at least a demonstration) of the Dyson series in Chapter 5.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  The shape of the matrix that produces the rotation is the same. It's the standard [cos - sin sin cos] thing. The angle simply changes. For constant angular velocity the angle is just $wt$. For constant acceleration it's just $\frac{1}{2} a t^2 + wt$. So you just put that in where you had $wt$.